# Conda can't install packages from requirements.txt available in conda-forge, although package exists in conda-forge

Tags: python, conda

I added conda-forge to the conda channels:

```
$ conda config --show channels
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
```

my requirements.txt contains, among others, these lines:

```
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
jupyter-client==6.1.12
jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
appnope==0.1.2
jupyterlab-widgets==1.0.0
data==0.4
prometheus-client==0.11.0
latex==0.7.0
scipy==1.5.4
jupyter-core==4.7.1
jupyter-console==6.4.0
async-generator==1.10
vg==1.10.0
sklearn==0.0
postgis==1.0.4
```

When I try to create a new environment from this requirements.txt using conda with

`conda create --name myenv --file requirements.txt`

I get the following errors:

```
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - ipython-genutils==0.2.0
  - jupyter-client==6.1.12
  - jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
  - appnope==0.1.2
  - jupyterlab-widgets==1.0.0
  - data==0.4
  - prometheus-client==0.11.0
  - latex==0.7.0
  - scipy==1.5.4
  - jupyter-core==4.7.1
  - jupyter-console==6.4.0
  - async-generator==1.10
  - vg==1.10.0
  - sklearn==0.0
  - postgis==1.0.4

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

As you can see, conda-forge is listed under "current channels" and [ipython-genutils==0.2.0 is available in conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/ipython_genutils). However, the package is not found. How can I fix this problem?

I tried both `conda config --set channel_priority flexible` and `... stable`

I run Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Python 3.10 and Conda 4.12.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like this should have been a requirements.txt to be used by pip. Note that `conda` packages can have slightly different names than what is available on pypi.

`ipython-genutils` is not the correct name, looking at the link you have provided, the name of the package is `ipython_genutils` with an underscore. The same is true for the other packages that you have written with a hyphen. They should all be spelled with an underscore.

That leaves

```
  - sklearn==0.0
  - latex==0.7.0
  - vg==1.10.0
  - scipy==1.5.4
  - postgis==1.0.4
  - data==0.4
  - appnope==0.1.2
```

`sklearn==0.0` seems to be a corrupt line in your file. The package's name is `scikit-learn`. `latex`, `vg` and `data` are not available on conda channels as far as I can tell. The same goes for `scipy==1.5.4`, only 1.5.3 and 1.6 are available. `postgis` only goes back to 2.4.3 on conda-forge , see [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/postgis/files?page=2), but also seems to be different from what is available on pypi. `appnope` is a package only available for macOS, see [it's description](https://pypi.org/project/appnope/):

> Simple package for disabling App Nap on macOS >= 10.9, which can be problematic.

So with that in mind, we can create a yml file that installs from both conda channels and from pip (Changes to your file: replaced `-` with `_`, removed `appnope`, added `pip` dependency, renamed `sklearn` to `scikit-learn` and moved it together with `latex`, `scipy`, `vg`, `data`, `postgis` to `pip` requirements. If you are flexible with  `scipy==1.5.4`, I would advise to change it to `scipy==1.5.3` or `scipy==1.6.0` and move `scipy` and `sklearn` out of the `pip` installed packages):

```
name: myenv
dependencies:
 - ipython_genutils==0.2.0
 - jupyter_client==6.1.12
 - jupyterlab_pygments==0.1.2
 - jupyterlab_widgets==1.0.0
 - prometheus_client==0.11.0
 - jupyter_core==4.7.1
 - jupyter_console==6.4.0
 - async_generator==1.10
 - pip
 - pip:
   - scikit-learn
   - latex==0.7.0
   - scipy==1.5.4
   - vg==1.10.0
   - data==0.4.0
   - postgis==1.0.4
```

Save this as `environment.yml` and then do

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

Comment: `sklearn` is a common mistake: that is the module name, but the package name is `scikit-learn`

Comment: Thanks merv, overlooked that since the environment did actually solve that way. I will rename